# Converting a Binary tree to a Binary Search Tree

Tags: c, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

So here I'm converting a Binary Tree to a Binary Search Tree by copying the  elements of the tree to an array.
Then,I'm sorting the array(bubble sort) and then traversing the tree using inorder traversal and copying the elements of the array to the tree.
Everything is working fine but the function void inr(Node *root) is not copying the elements as in a binary search tree I should get elements in the increasing order(inorder traversal) but I'm not getting a proper output.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
   int x=0;
   int l=0;
   typedef struct node
   {
      int data;
      struct node *rlink;
      struct node *llink;
   } Node;
   Node *getnode()
   {
      Node *temp=(Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
      return temp;
   }
   int a[10];
   int i=0;
   Node *create(Node *root,int key)
   {
      int c;
      if(root==NULL)
      {
         root=getnode();
         root->rlink=root->llink=NULL;
         root->data=key;
      }
      else
      {
         printf("Enter where you want to enter 1.RIGHT 2.LEFT");
         scanf("%d",&c);
         switch(c)
         {
            case 1:root->rlink=create(root->rlink,key);
                   break;
            case 2:root->llink=create(root->llink,key);
                   break;
            default:printf("Wrong choice");
            break;
         }
     }
     return root;
}

void inorder(Node *root) //to copy the contents  of the tree in the array
{
   if(root!=NULL)
   {
      inorder(root->rlink);
      if(root->data>0) a[i++]=root->data;
      inorder(root->llink);
   }
}

void utu(Node *h) //For inorder traversal
{
   if(h!=NULL)
   {
      utu(h->rlink);
      printf("%d",h->data);
      utu(h->llink);
   }
}

void inr(Node *root) //to copy the elements of sorted array in the tree to make it a BST
{
   if(root==NULL) return;
   else if(root!=NULL)
   {
      inr(root->llink);
      root->data=a[l++];
      inr(root->rlink);
   }
}

void main()
{
   int j=0;
   int temp=0;
   Node *h=NULL;
   h=create(h,5);
   h=create(h,6);
   h=create(h,7);
   h=create(h,8);
   inorder(h);
   count(h);
   printf("%d \n",x);
   printf("\n \n \n");
   for(j=0;j<x;j++)
   {
      printf("%d \n",a[j]);
   }
   for(int i=0;i<x;i++) //bubble sorting of the array obtained by copying the nodes data in the array
   {
      for(j=i+1;j<x;j++)
      {
         if(a[i]>a[j])
         {
            temp=a[i];
            a[i]=a[j];
            a[j]=temp;
         }
      }
  }
  utu(h);
  //for(j=0;j<x;j++)
  //{
  //    printf("\n %d \n",a[j]);
  //}
  printf("\n \n");
  //j=maxd(h);
  //printf("%d",j);
  inr(h);
  utu(h);
}
```

Comment: Please tell us what you see as output, and what you expect to see.

Comment: `utu` is going right-then-left, but `inr` is going left-then-right.

Comment: @BadZen I want 5678 to come and I'm getting 8765 as the output

Comment: It sounds as if you're sorting in the wrong order, or inserting in the wrong order.